# If, else based on command piped to grep

Tags: linux, macos, bash, grep, parallels

I can't figure out how to make this (what supposed to be simple) script to work. Basically what I want, to run different stuff based on the state of my Parallels vm, something like this:

```
if [ prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm | grep State == "State: running" ] ; then 
   echo 'machine is running'
else
   echo 'machine is not running'
fi
```

Of course that doesn't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting it all within `[`, i.e. the `test` command.  Moreover, your usage of `grep` is broken.

All you need is:

```
if prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm | grep -q "State: running"; then
   echo 'machine is running'
else
   echo 'machine is not running'
fi
```

Note the usage of `-q` as an argument to `grep`.  It doesn't write anything to STDOUT and exits with a status of 0 if the match is found, and non-zero otherwise.

Comment: A oneliner: `prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm | grep -q "State: running" && echo "machine is running" || echo "machine is not running"`

Answer (score 5):

An alternative check, less "clean" but closer to what the question tried to achieve.

Remember that `[` at its core is just a command. It always accepts a specific number of parameters, and exits with either 0 (success) or 1 (failure) exit status, as all other commands do. For example, when you're comparing two strings, the syntax is`[`, string 1, `==`, string 2, `]`.

Right now you're using this as the `if` condition:

```
[ prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm | grep State == "State: running" ]
```

But it's ambiguous in several ways. How would `[` know that on the left you have a command to run and not a fixed string? How would it know that the `==` is the string comparison operator, rather than just an argument to `grep`? How would it know that the `|` is part of the left-hand value, rather than separating the command into  `[ prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm` and `grep State == "State: running" ]`?

So the left side needs to be quoted as well. Also, since you want to compare the *output* of that command, rather than the worlds "prctl list --info..." themselves, you need the `$(…)` operator:

```
[ "$(prlctl list --info ubuntu-vm | grep State)" == "State: running" ]
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. May I ask, Where have you gained you Shell-Scripting skills? I would love to read something about the Shell, that goes into that detail, like that `[` is a command, what probably seems very foreign to someone for whom knows only languages like Java or Python.

Comment: @Creaturo: It's a scripting language by design, intended to link  together shell commands, so it makes sense that the `if` statement would accept an arbitrary command as the condition (`if <command>; then <commands...>; fi`). The syntax is described in `man bash` if you're working with the 'bash' shell.

Comment: This was a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

IF we have below in txt files and want to grep multiple string.

### minion1:

```
      ID: php_install
Function: pkg.installed
    Name: php
  Result: True
 Comment: All specified packages are already installed
 Started: 16:19:04.217642
Duration: 587.977 ms
```

We can use below grep statement:-

**grep -Po '(ID|(?Function)|(?Duration)): (?(fun)\w+.\w+|(?(dur)\d+.\d+ ms|\w+))' high.yxy**

To clarify above, I am doing

P means using **pcre**

o means it will give only the **matches output**

?<fun> its a name of **function named group**

I hope this will resolve your issue.